# if i have the message like this in c language ".exe has stopped working"?

Tags: c, windows

I have a problem in c language that when I run the program
the message "x.exe has stopped working".
for example x is the name of the file.
how can I fix it?

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct student
{
int  id;
char *firs_name;
char *last_name;
char *email;
};

struct datetime
{
int date;
int  time;
};
typedef struct student student;
typedef struct datetime datetime;

struct submission
{
student *stud1;
student *stud2;
datetime *dt;
};

typedef struct submission submission;

int details(submission *data, int n1, datetime due_date, int *lates);
submission *return_clear_arr(submission *data,int n1);


submission *return_clear_arr(submission *data,int n1)
{
int i,j;

 for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
   for(j=1;j<n1;j++)
    {
    if(data[i].stud1->id==data[j].stud1->id && data[i].stud2->id==data  [j].stud2->id)
        {

            data[j].stud1->id=-1;
            data[j].stud2->id=-1;
        }
        if(data[i].stud1->id==data[j].stud1->id)
        {
          data[j].stud1->id=-1;
        }
        if(data[i].stud1->id==data[j].stud2->id)
        {
            data[j].stud2->id=-1;
        }
        if(data[i].stud2->id==data[j].stud1->id)
        {
         data[j].stud1->id=-1;
        }
        if(data[i].stud2->id==data[j].stud2->id)
        {
           data[j].stud2->id =-1;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

}
return data;
}

int details(submission *data, int n1, datetime due_date, int *lates)
{
int i,counter=0,counter1=0;
submission *data2;
data2=return_clear_arr(data,n1);

for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
  if(data[i].dt->date < due_date.date)
  {
    if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
     counter++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
        counter+=2;
    }
  }
  if(data[i].dt->date > due_date.date)
  {
   if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        counter1++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
     counter1++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
        counter1+=2;
    }
  }
  if(data[i].dt->date == due_date.date && data[i].dt->time < due_date.time)
  {
    if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
     counter++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
        counter+=2;
    }
  }
  if(data[i].dt->date == due_date.date && data[i].dt->time > due_date.time)
  {
   if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id==-1)
    {
        counter1++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id==-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
     counter1++;
    }
    if( data[i].stud1->id!=-1 && data[i].stud2->id!=-1)
    {
        counter1+=2;
    }
  }
}
*lates=counter1;
return counter;
}

int main()
{
int n1=6,result1;
int *lates1;
datetime due_date1={14314,1200};
submission data1[6];
submission sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6;
sub1.stud1[0].id= 23423446;
sub1.stud1[1].firs_name ="Yoram";
sub1.stud1[2].last_name= "Givon";
sub1.stud1[3].email= "yoram@gmail.com";
sub1.stud2[0].id= 823654434;
sub1.stud2[1].firs_name ="Mor";
sub1.stud2[2].last_name= "Kol";
sub1.stud2[3].email= "mor@gmail.com";
sub1.dt->date=13314;
sub1.dt->time=2000;
data1[0]=sub1;

sub2.stud1[0].id= 423423467;
sub2.stud1[1].firs_name ="Uri";
sub2.stud1[2].last_name= "Kaplan";
sub2.stud1[3].email= "uri@gmail.com";
sub2.stud2[0].id= 834654434;
sub2.stud2[1].firs_name ="Naama";
sub2.stud2[2].last_name= "Vilk";
sub2.stud2[3].email= "naama@gmail.com";
sub2.dt->date=12314;
sub2.dt->time=2000;
data1[1]=sub2;

sub3.stud1[0].id= 482634546;
sub3.stud1[1].firs_name ="Uriel";
sub3.stud1[2].last_name= "Shalom";
sub3.stud1[3].email= "uriel@gmail.com";
sub3.dt->date=14314;
sub3.dt->time=1100;
data1[2]=sub3;

sub4.stud1[0].id= 429283243;
sub4.stud1[1].firs_name ="Omer";
sub4.stud1[2].last_name= "Chen";
sub4.stud1[3].email= "omer@gmail.com";
sub4.stud2[0].id= 423654434;
sub4.stud2[1].firs_name ="Dan";
sub4.stud2[2].last_name= "Lerner";
sub4.stud2[3].email= "dan@gmail.com";
sub4.dt->date=13314;
sub4.dt->time=1000;
data1[3]=sub4;

sub5.stud1[0].id= 492381236;
sub5.stud1[1].firs_name ="Amit";
sub5.stud1[2].last_name= "Paz";
sub5.stud1[3].email= "amit@gmail.com";
sub5.dt->date=13314;
sub5.dt->time=800;
data1[4]=sub5;

sub6.stud1[0].id= 745919897;
sub6.stud1[1].firs_name ="Dikla";
sub6.stud1[2].last_name= "Gefen";
sub6.stud1[3].email= "dikla@gmail.com";
sub6.stud2[0].id= 925962312;
sub6.stud2[1].firs_name="Yaara";
sub6.stud2[2].last_name= "Shaked";
sub6.stud2[3].email= "yaara@gmail.com";
sub6.dt->date=14314;
sub6.dt->time=1159;
data1[5]=sub6;
result1=details(data1,n1,due_date1,lates1);
printf("%d",result1);
return 0;
}
```

hi, I have a problem in c language that when I run the program
the message "x.exe has stopped working".
for example x is the name of the file.
how can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried debugging? where is this error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the time to lean how to use your IDE's debugger and how to review your code and any compiler warnings you get.  Your problem is in main():

Here, you create a bunch of submission structs instances:

```
submission sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6;
```

Then, you try to do this assignment:

```
sub1.stud1[0].id= 23423446;
```

If you look at the declaration of submission:

```
struct submission
{
student *stud1;
student *stud2;
datetime *dt;
};
```

You will see that stud1, is a **pointer** to a student, not a student.  So no memory has been allocated for the struct.  The pointer is pointing to garbage.  You then attempt to de-reference the pointer, and blam, segfault.  You need to initialize it to a valid memory block of a student type.  That is left to you as a learning exercise.

Comment: ok,i change this and all the "->",so is still do the problem. how can i do debbuging?